# Is it possible to find previous saved times used 'datetime.datetime.now()' to save in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I am reading some data and save it into the `.xlsx` files using following code:

```
name_file = path + str(datetime.datetime.now()).replace(':','-').replace(' ','_')
point_index = name_file.find('.')
name_file = name_file[:point_index ] + '.xlsx'
link = 'http://...'
resp = requests.get(link)
output = open(name_file, 'wb')
output.write(resp.content)
output.close()
```

What I want to do is to load last 2 or 3 or any number of saved files and compare them together. if we consider `name_file = path + str(datetime.datetime.now()).replace(':','-').replace(' ','_')` consist the name of the last saved file, how is it possible to load the previous file of this file?

I also must mention that the name of the files don't have regular distances. They look like below:

```
2020-08-02_10-23-46.xlsx
2020-08-02_10-23-58.xlsx
2020-08-02_10-24-09.xlsx
2020-08-02_10-24-49.xlsx
2020-08-02_10-25-00.xlsx
```

Comment: i would sort the file names and pick the last *N* that you want. `sorted(pathlib.Path('.'').glob('*.xlsx'))[-3:]`

Comment: also, to format datetime objects, have a look at https://strftime.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all xlsx files under the current directory are generated from the process you described, then I suggest you simply sort the files by their name (which will also put them in chronological order due to the way you named them), then select the last 2 or whatever number of files you want.

For example:

```
import os
selected = sorted(filename for filename in os.listdir('.') if filename.endswith('.xlsx'))[-2:]
```

Comment: `if filename.endswith('.xlsx')` to avoid the fiddly slicing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

`return sorted(os.listdir(path), key=lambda x: os.path.getctime(os.path.join(path, x)))[-3:]`

where -3: is amount of files from tail (latest 3). You can use any other sort of slicing as well.

Comment: I think this will give the first three files, not the last three

Comment: Good catch. Always get them mixed up even after using them hundreds of times aha.

Comment: That will give you all files _except_ the first three. I think you're looking for `[-3:]` to get the last ones...